# Hovering over navigation bar item shows content with lower z-index

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, z-index

When user is hovering over one of the links in menu, the background behind the menu is showing. This wrong rendering is only in Chrome, and only on one specific pc, so it is a bit hard for me to debug as for me and other computers I tried it, it worked without problem.

On the picture you can see that the map which is behind the menu is visible when hovering over menu item. But it is not only the map, also anything that is under it. The text of the menu item when hovered is visible, with white background and it can be clicked. Only some area around it is corrupted.

[image]

I'm using [Yamm megamenu for Bootstrap](http://geedmo.github.io/yamm/)

and standard Bootstrap 3.3 dropdown menu.

This is part of the code for the menu (it is generated in php as it is a plugin for yii)

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="yw4">
<ul id="yw2" class="nav navbar-nav" role="menu">
  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Menu item</a></li>
  <li class="dropdown open">
     <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Menu item megamenu <b class="caret"></b></a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="yt2" aria-labelledby="yt2" role="menu">
        <li class="dropdown-header">
           <!-- Content container to add padding -->
           <div class="yamm-content">
              <div class="row">
                 <ul class="col-sm-2 list-unstyled">
                    <li>
                       <p><strong>Megamenu subheader</strong></p>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                       <table>
                          <tbody>
                             <tr>
                                <td style="width:30px">
                                   <div class="imgs"></div>
                                </td>
                                <td style="max-width:90px">
                                   <a href="#">Menu item with problems</a>
                                </td>
                             </tr>
                          </tbody>
                       </table>
                    </li>
                 </ul>
              </div>
           </div>
        </li>
     </ul>
  </li>
  <li visible="1"><a tabindex="-1" href="">Other menu item</a></li>
  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="">Other menu item</a></li>
  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="">Other menu item</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Css

```
.dropdown-menu {
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
left: 0;
z-index: 1000;
display: none;
float: left;
min-width: 160px;
padding: 5px 0;
margin: 2px 0 0;
list-style: none;
font-size: 14px;
text-align: left;
background-color: #ffffff;
border: 1px solid #cccccc;
border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
border-radius: 4px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
background-clip: padding-box;
}

.dropdown-menu {
z-index:100010;
```

}

Comment: since it only happens to one pc, have you tried clearing the browser cache on that pc?

Comment: @Mindless user has been viewing the website also using incognito window, so cache shouldn't be the problem